# Change http.sys registry settings on Windows Azure?

Tags: registry, azure, http.sys

I would need to raise the UrlSegmentMaxLength of the [Http.sys registry settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129) on Windows Azure. Does anyone knows how to do that? (or do something that leads to an equivalent behavior)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like those reg keys are in HKLM.  I don't believe you can change those without admin access (which you don't have in Windows Azure today).

Unless there's another way to override that (like in web.config), I think you're out of luck until admin mode comes.

Comment: Argh, such a pain, for reasons that are beyond me, it seems that there is no possible override in web.config over the registry settings. Thanks for the quick follow-up though.

Comment: Hello Steve, 'bkaid' below, based on your blog post, suggests to the use of a startup task to override http.sys registry settings on Azure. Do you confirm it would work?

Comment: Yup, I would think this would work now that we have elevated privileges.

Answer (score 8):

1) Add a .cmd file to your web project. Set Build Action to “None” and Copy to Output Directory to “Copy always”.

2) Update .cmd file. Here is the example script I used which checks to see if the registry change has been set, and if it hasn't modify the registry and then reboot the server (reboot required - simply restarting the http service causes the azure deployment to go in a never ending loop).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set regpath=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters
reg query "%regpath%" /v "AllowRestrictedChars"
if errorlevel 1 (
   reg add %regpath% /v AllowRestrictedChars /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
   reg add %regpath% /v UrlSegmentMaxCount /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
   reg add %regpath% /v PercentUAllowed /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
   reg add %regpath% /v UrlSegmentMaxLength /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
   shutdown /r /t 0
)
```

3) In your Azure role’s servicedefinition.csdef, add the .cmd as a startup task:

```
<WebRole name="WebRoleName">
  ...
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="httpSys.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
  </Startup>
</WebRole>
```

4) Deploy your Azure role and the registry changes should have taken place.

Comment: I am encountering the same endless loop with the worker roles that are in the same servicedefinition.csdef